# the problem with the authorization token in nifi

Tags: json, api, http, apache-nifi, invoke

The response from the API in json format is not displayed due to the fact that I cannot find where to put the authorization token, which is registered in headers in Postman. Where do I need to add this token to InvokeHTTP? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocD4q.png)

I tried to substitute the token in the http url as a key, I tried to connect the Request OAuth2 Access Token Provider, but it gives an error

Comment: what token? where did you get it? how you are passing token in postman?

Comment: @daggett , in order for the Api request to work for me, in Postman in headers in the key you need to specify - Authorization, and in Value - Token 5f01befe0a... only then will the body come to me with all the information in the API. If you do not do this, you will receive a body with an error - "error": 1, "details": "Invalid session.

Comment: Read about `Request Header Attributes Pattern` parameter. It describes 2 options how to send headers. https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.19.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/index.html